# is versus is of

Tags: usage

I am not sure whether "***is***" and "***is of***" are the same thing. After some internet search, I still could not figure out their discrepancy.

To further the discussion, here are two examples:

> - i) Contemporary art ***is lower in quality*** than earlier art.
> - ii) Contemporary art ***is of lower quality*** than earlier art.

Could anyone please explain their difference in terms of implication and tone?

Comment: You can include ***either or neither*** (but not ***both***) of the prepositions ***in*** and ***of*** in your cited context. They're all syntactically fine, and it makes no difference to the meaning which version you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in meaning is subtle and doesn't matter in most instances, but:

> Contemporary art is of lower quality than earlier art.

You're saying "lower quality" is derived from "contemporary art" - so you are saying contemporary art is lower quality because it's contemporary.

> Contemporary art is lower in quality than earlier art.

You're saying contemporary art is lower in quality than X, but you are only *implying* that it is because it is contemporary.  Technically, something else besides the fact that the art is contemporary could be causing the lower quality.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly *is* and *is of* are not the same. We wouldn't say *my cup is of full* or *that man is of tall.*

The examples you give highlight a different issue; the distinction between *low in quality* and *of low quality*. These are two ways of expressing the same idea. Similarly, we can describe a person as being *short in stature* or *of short stature*. Both forms are equally correct and acceptable.